# JButtons appearing and disappearing with mouse

Tags: java, user-interface, mouse, jframe, jbutton

When I add several JButtons to this JFrame, the buttons appear and disappear with mouse movements...kinda spooky. Any Ideas? Other Projects dont have this issue, therefore im pretty sure its my code...but its so simple im not sure whats wrong!

Full Code: (I blurred out my name)

```
package explorerplus;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExplorerPlus {

//Declarations
Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
 JFrame f = new JFrame();

public static void main(String[] args) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            ExplorerPlus ep = new ExplorerPlus();
        }
    });
}
private ExplorerPlus(){
   // f.super("");
    f.setUndecorated(false);

    f.setSize(t.getScreenSize());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c = null;
    c =new JScrollPane(c);
    f.setContentPane(c);
    f.setVisible(true);
    GoThrough(new File("C:/Users/*****/Pictures/"));
    f.repaint();
 }
  static int spc_count=-1;
  int curr_x = 10, curr_y = 10;
  void GoThrough(File aFile) {
spc_count++;
String spcs = "";
for (int i = 0; i < spc_count; i++)
  spcs += " ";
if(aFile.isFile()){
  System.out.println(spcs + "[FILE] " + aFile.getName());
  File file = aFile;
  String s = getExt(file) + ".png";
  JButton b = new JButton(new ImageIcon(s));
  b.setToolTipText(file.getName());
  b.setSize(256, 256);
  b.setLocation(curr_x, curr_y);
  b.setVisible(true);
  b.validate();
  f.validate();

  if(curr_x < f.getWidth() - 270){
      curr_x+=270;
  }else{
  curr_y+=270;
  curr_x = 10;
  }
  f.getContentPane().add(b);


}
else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
  System.out.println(spcs + "[DIR] " + aFile.getName());
  File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
  if(listOfFiles!=null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
      GoThrough(listOfFiles[i]);
  } else {
    System.out.println(spcs + " [ACCESS DENIED]");
  }
}
spc_count--;
}

  String getExt(File f){

 if(f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")|| f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")){
     return "jpeg";
 } else if(f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")){
     return "png";
 }
 else if(f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".html")){
     return "html";
 }else if(f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".ini")){
     return "ini";
 }else{
     return "text";
 }
  }
  String AllButExt(File f){
      String name = f.getName();
      return name.replace(getExt(f), "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to narrow your code down to a small, relevant portion. It's difficult and time-consuming to read your entire source code- a more compact example will net you more answers.

Comment: And more careful attention to the formatting/indentation would help the casual reader.

Comment: your code looks spooky to say the least!

Comment: `f.getContentPane()` will have a layout manager installed - but you are using absolute sizing and positioning. This may be the culprit (and requires `f.getContentPane().setLayout(null)`).

Comment: [off-topic]: The convention for Java method names is `lowercaseStartingCamelCase()`.  As such, `GoThrough(File aFile)` should be `goThrough(File aFile)` - similarly for `AllButExt(File f)`.

Comment: But you don't want to use absolute sizing as Swing does not work well with this. Much better is to use the various layout managers in combination to achieve decent GUI's that work well on all platforms. And that his your problem: you aren't using them.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did undestand you right: you wants to display a new JButton on your JFrame. But it doesn't appear.

If so you can try to use:

```
f.updateUI();
```

After you have added the button to the frame.